# Problem about arithmetic and general harmonic progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series

> An arithmetic progression and a general harmonic progression have the same first term, the same last term and the same number of terms. Prove that the product of the $r$th term from the beginning in one series and the $r$th term from the end in the other is independent of $r$.

Please help me prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k$th term of a AP is $a+k d_1$, while the $k$th term of an HP is $a/(1+k d_2)$.  Under the constraints of having the first and last terms agree, and the progressions having the same number of terms (say, $n$), we have

$$a+n d_1 = \frac{a}{1+n d_2} $$

This gives us a relation between $d_1$ and $d_2$:

$$d_1 = -\frac{a d_2}{1+n d_2}$$

Now, the problems asserts that the product of the $r$th term from the beginning of one sequence (say, the AP) and the $r$th term from the end of the other sequence (the HP) is independent of $r$.  Well, let's write the $r$th term of the AP:

$$a+r d_1 = a - \frac{r a d_2}{1+n d_2} = \frac{a+(n-r) a d_2}{1+n d_2}$$

Now, the $r$th term from the end of the HP is  $a/(1+(n-r) d_2)$.  We then have the product being

$$(a+r d_1) \frac{a}{1+(n-r) d_2}  = \frac{a+(n-r) a d_2}{1+n d_2} \frac{a}{1+(n-r) d_2} = \frac{a^2}{1+n d_2}$$

which is independent of $r$.

Comment: I have been taught that the kth term of an AP is a+(k-1)d while the kth term of an HP is 1/a+(k-1)d. Please explain the relation between this term and the one you have used for the kth term of AP and HP.

Comment: @TejasAdsul: no offense, but...really?  It's a convention - some say the first term corresponds to $k=1$, others at $k=0$.  It is of little import.  And if you insist on being that rigid, then I fear that there is little hope of your understanding any solution posed here.

Comment: I understood the solution now. Thank you very much.